# HTC Desire HD Micro sd Card Ejects

Tags: external-sd, htc-desire

I had just bought a new Micro sd card and it worked fine, but suddenly the card physically ejects all the time, it wont sit in the micro sd reader. When I try to format the card on the on my phone, it won't finish the processes. I have tried formatting the card on my laptop, but it does not give an effect. I tried to format it on my phone, but that does not work. I also tried on my laptop with 32 byte fat32. Any suggestions